# Jquery how to select with a given type and a given class

Tags: jquery

I want to select from my html code all the tags that are both of a type and of a class.

For example, let's say I wanted all the dd tags with a class of "error". I'd want the example to work as follows.

```
<div class="group">
  <dl class="error">
    <dt>
      <label for="Number">Number</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Keep this one
    </dd>
    <dd class="error">
      Not this one
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

I want something along the lines of

```
$('.group').children("dd").find('.error').remove();
```

to return

```
<div class="group">
  <dl class="error">
    <dt>
      <label for="Number">Number</label>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      Keep this one
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.group dd.error').remove()`  should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tag and class name in combination.

```
$(".group dd.error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".group").find("dd.error").remove();
```